# JavaScript Hacking

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to figure out any and all ways to prevent CSS modification and DOM modification of specific elements. I understand this might not be completely possible or that a talented developer could get around it, however, I am not so concerned about people potentially getting around it, I just want to stop newbies. In particular those using jQuery. An example would be to delete certain properties on prototype objects etc..

Comment: Short of obfuscating all your code and using Javascript to load stuff, also obfuscated, there's not much you can do. Have a look at what, for instance, Korean news websites like http://www.vitaminnews.co.kr/ do to prevent people to mess with their stuff (and it's still possible to tear down most of their "defenses")...

Comment: You want to somehow disallow people from running JS code in their browser? No. Any checks you put into place can probably be removed just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

But why you need/want this? If you want to "protect" your code, you can use some JavaScript minifier as Google Closure Compiler or YUI compressor. They will rewrite your script and it will be difficult to read by a human. Nowadays, with tools like Firebug and Grease Monkey it's almost impossible to do what you want.

Comment: *"...prevent CSS modification and DOM modification..."* not the code, it seems.

Comment: @Hamish: As I said, **IF** he wants to "protect". CSS and DOM modification are easily performed with the tools that I said too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CSS or JavaScript :p Depend completely on server side checks etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KenY-N Frankly, this does answer the question. Any client-side prevention can easily be bypassed. All essential verification must be done server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop anyone from messing with your javascript or your objects in the page.  The way the browser is designed, your code and objects in your page are simply not protected.  Everything from bookmarklets to javascript entered at a console to browser plug-ins can mess with your page and code and variables.  That is the architecture of a browser.

What you can do is make things a little more difficult such that a little more work is required for some things.  Here are a couple of things you could do:

1. Obfuscating/compressing/minimizing your code will do things like remove comments, remove whitespace, remove some linebreaks, shorten variable names, etc...   That does not prevent anyone from modifying things, but does make it more work to understand and figure out.
2. Putting variables inside closures and not using globals.  This makes it harder to directly modify variables from outside of your scripts.
3. Keep all important data and secrets on your server.  Use ajax calls to ask the server to carry out operations using that data or secrets such that the important information is never available in the browser client.

You cannot keep anyone from modifying the DOM.  There simply are no protections against that.  Your code can check the DOM and refuse to operate if the DOM has been messed with in non-standard ways.  But, of course, the code would then be modified to remove that check too.

Comment: I have now discovered this is incorrect. The reason this is actually possible is you can permanently affect how javascript runs in any particular instance. Let me give you a rudimentary example.

If I overwrite document.write and do not store the function anywhere else, you cannot easily retrieve it. Now you could possibly run plugins etc.. but you wouldn't be able to write a client side javascript that could fix it after it is lost.

The way around this would you would have to hot load the JS file and modify it in real-time but if your code is obfuscated it would require an expert level dev.

Comment: @JonathanWagner - What are you going to try to do - replace all DOM modification functions on all objects with functions that do nothing?  Good luck with a practical application doing that.  If I want to, I can just intercept your code as it's downloading to your page through a proxy and modify it before it even gets to the page or insert my own JS before yours (capturing all those functions).  Client-side javascript is simply not secure in any possible way.  The browser was not designed to solve problems like that.  If you want a secure client-side environment, you will need a different tool.

Comment: @JonathanWagner - actually, it took me about 3 minutes to retrieve a fresh copy of `document.write()` by making a new iframe and getting it from that new/fresh document.  See here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/L401bod5/ for implementation.

Comment: The type of developer that has that kind of capability are not the kind of developers I was targeting my security at. If you're the type of developer that would go through the effort of modifying closure compiled javascript code at download, you probably are not working at an enterprise level.

Comment: Actually it is writing to the iframe, not the parent. So you didn't exactly recover the original function. Which is actually really interesting because in this particular instance the function is by ref.

Comment: @JonathanWagner - I don't think so.  The text still displays even if I remove the iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/74ccrpeh/.  If you're looking at the DOM inspector, you have to realize that jsFiddle itself is using an iframe for the main content.

Comment: @JonathanWagner - There is a difference between security and roadblocks that serve as obstacles, but don't actually stop a determined hacker.  Roadblocks are OK to use as long as you know what you are getting and that really serves your purpose.  You should just make sure you don't get these two things confused because a roadblock is not actually security and won't actually provide you with security.  You'd likely be wrong if you assume all enterprise developers would be stumped by roadblocks.  As for me, I'm a retired software developer - did five silicon valley startups.

Comment: Oh I know the difference, what I meant is that enterprise developers are less likely to do do something like break TOU by modifying code on the fly.

Comment: @JonathanWagner - I reread your original question from 3 months ago and it's really too general to comment further.  There are no absolute protections here.  Everything has some sort of limitations that can be bypassed so meaningful advice can only be offered after understanding exactly what you want to protect, why you want to protect it, what the consequences are of not protecting it, who your normal audience is and what would be the ramifications of a smarter-than-average-bear getting through your roadblocks.  You've disclosed none of that.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a jquery specific solution a crude approach will involve altering the jQuery ($) function and replacing it with a custom one that delegates to the original function only if the provided selector does not match the element you want to secure.

`(function(){
jQueryOrig = jQuery;
window.jQuery = window.$ = function(){
    if (jQueryOrig("#secure").is(arguments[0])) { 
        throw new Error("Security breach"); 
    } else return jQueryOrig.apply(this, arguments);
}
}());`

Of course people using direct DOM manipulation would not be affected.

Also, if you are actually including arbitrary third party code in your production code, you should take a look at Caja ( http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/ ), which limits users to a subset of javascript capabilities. There is a good explanation regarding Caja here : http://due-diligence.typepad.com/blog/2008/04/web-20-investor.html .

Answer (score -1):

This is possible but requires that the JS file to always be loaded from your server. Using observers you can lock CSS properties and using the on DOM remove/add listeners you can lock it to a parent. This will be enough to discourage most modification.

You can actually go a step further and modify core javascript functions making it nearly impossible to modify the DOM without loading the JS file locally or through a proxy. Further security can be added by doing additional domain checks to make sure the JS file is loaded from where it is supposed to be loaded from.

Answer (score -1):

You can make everything in Flash.  In Chrome, there's even a bug that prevents users from opening a console if the flash element has focus (not sure how exactly this works, but you can see an example at http://www.twist-cube.com or http://www.gotmilk.com).  Even if users do manage to get a console open (which isn't that hard...), still about all you can do is change the shape of the element.